# Что не так с моим asyncio

Tags: python, веб-программирование, asyncio

Пытаюсь понять дзен asyncio. Пишу рекурсивный парсер. Работает безумно медленно. В чем может быть проблема?

```
async def asynchronous(URL, session, depths=0, regExpPattern='/wiki/.*', 
                    parentid=1, max_depths=MAX_DEPTHS, db=DB, sem=SEM):
    if depths <= max_depths:
        nowid = insertPagesTB(URL, depths, db)
        insertRelationsTB(parentid, nowid, db)
        hrefs = []
        async with sem:
            async with session.get(URL) as response:
                response = await response.read()
                page = BeautifulSoup(response)
                for row in page.findAll("a", href=True):
                    if re.fullmatch(regExpPattern, row["href"]):
                        hrefs.append(row["href"])
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(asynchronous(("https://en.wikipedia.org"+i), 
            session=session, depths=depths+1, parentid=nowid)) for i in hrefs[:3]]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def startFetching(URL, conn=CONN):
    async with ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:
        task = [asyncio.ensure_future(asynchronous(URL, session=session))]
        await asyncio.gather(*task)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(startFetching(START_URL))
```

Comment: Засекайте, что именно здесь работает безумно медленно. Так как вы выложили не весь код и не составили [mcve], запустить его у себя мы не сможем и что-то дельное вряд ли ответим

Comment: @andreymal спасибо Вам за ответ! вот весь код: https://github.com/commonDrafts/skytreck/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Если я правильно вчитался в код, вы в бесконечной рекурсии полностью захватываете все 1000 мест не показанного в вопросе семафора, и весь скрипт дружно дохнет под мёртвыми блокировками. Точно не уверен, но, возможно, следует вынести весь блок `if len(hrefs) != 0` из-под `async with sem` — полную работоспособность не проверял, но скрипт хотя бы немного начинает шевелиться

Comment: И не стесняйтесь ставить `print(URL)` после `async with sem`, чтобы видеть, что вообще происходит

Comment: Возможно, sqlalchemy не имеет отношения к проблеме «дзена asyncio»; выкиньте его упоминание из кода и поместите оставшееся в текст вопроса, иначе он окажется закрыт как не содержащий минимального воспроизводимого примера

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое Вам за ответы. Пускаю тесты для hrfes[:5] и глубиной 6 уровней: пишет больше 1000, вроде как все норм. Меня смущает именно скорость, тот факт, что в коде нет нормальной обработки исключений и так далее - это да, соглашусь, стыдно, но это только ради тестов писалось. При глубине 6, и hrefs[:2], 127 записей пишет секунд 5. Удивительно мало!

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое Вам за ответ. Буду разбираться - приведу решение, когда найду/пойму.

Comment: А ещё у вас код в вопросе и на гитхабе весьма сильно различаются - и непонятно, к чему относятся мои комментарии и какой следует обсуждать